# beans.xml not found in Spring. Problem with xml definition

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, annotations

My problem is that i get a stack trace with "Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'." when I start my Spring-App. I'm following a tutorial and there has been said that I should switch the definiton from my beans.xml to start with annotation configuration.

I have switcht it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-5.1.8.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-5.1.8.xsd">

<!-- <bean id="vehicle" class="com.dpi.Dependency_Injection_Spring_App.Bike"></bean> -->     
</beans>
```

The privious was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="vehicle" class="com.dpi.Dependency_Injection_Spring_App.Bike"></bean>

</beans>
```

Since I have canged the code do not find the beans.xml. I'm working with Spring version 5.1.8.RELESE. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You are following an obsolete tutorial. I recommend starting with the official Spring Getting Started Guides for Spring Boot, and then perhaps resources from Baeldung.

Comment: I wanted to Start with Spring first to get a better understanding and then go to spring boot. Would you recommend to start with boot?

Comment: Absolutely. Boot is the way that modern Spring is done; starting with legacy configuration and deployment is like building a rotary telephone. Starting with Boot will allow you to focus on the important concepts (like how to structure your application to support injection), and then you can explore the details once you have more context.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the advice.